# Securely storing a Facebook image url (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**BACKGROUND:** I am using Facebook Connect to gather users' Facebook image URL (i.e. http://graph.facebook.com/111111/picture) where 111111 is each user's Facebook ID.

**OBJECTIVE:** To store the image URL in a way in which the Facebook ID in the URL isn't outwardly visible (meaning that another user won't be able to figure out who the user is simply by right-clicking 'copy image url' and looking at the ID in the url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer can be found here: [Get redirect of a URL in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872210/get-redirect-of-a-url-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

Write a script that will download the image from FB's server, then output the image.

IE: www.yoururl.com/viewimage?id=UNIQUE_TOKEN_ASSOCIATED_WITH_FB_ACCOUNT

So when someone sees the url, they just see a unique token that maps to the FB id in your database.